# Dimension reduction using PCA in matlab code

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, dataset, pca

I have the matrix of `[152 X 27578]` 152 samples and 27578 features and I used the PCA function for the dimension reduction in matlab.

```
X = load(dataset); 
coeff = pca(X);
```

It generated a matrix of `[27578 X 151]`.But I dont understand what exactly it is generating and I am unable to understand what to do next. Can any one help me the understanding?. My main goal is to reduce the dimension of my original matrix

Comment: Your question is what does PCA do and how should you interpret and use it? That is way off topic for stackoverflow. I would normally say ask this at [stats.se] but really before you can ask anything there you will need to do your own research . There are plenty of free online resources from MOOCs (check out Andrew Ng's machine learning course on coursera) to excellent books ([intro to statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/getbook.html)) to random websites (http://setosa.io/ev/principal-component-analysis/).

Comment: it looks like you've not really understood what PCA is about - and without understanding, it is very hard to go forward. I would suggest understanding what feature dimension reduction is all about first - the 2 commands you will be using are `pca` and `pcares`.